# Signing one iOS project both Apple Enterprise and Apple Standart Account

Tags: ios, app-store, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate

I am developing and testing ios apps via Apple Enterprise Account in my organization. But when my developing and testing process ends I want to publish our app via Apple Store. When I try to sign this app with Standard Developer Account, Apple says that your app should have different bundle id.

I've added sample image that shows my situation.

So my question is how to manage both Apple Enterprise and Apple Standart Developer Account for one project.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: There is a TeamID prefix, that should be different in both dev accs and should prevent such issue. 
Not sure, how to help  you. Maybe it is a good idea to change bundle id? 
com.org.helloworld.dev  for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot register the same bundle ID twice. Our team has 2 bundle IDs `com.organization.helloworld` (app store bundle ID) & `com.organization.helloworld.beta` (enterprise account bundle ID). This is cool, because it allows both version of the app to be on the device at the same time.

This may seems like a pain to manage, but you can set the "Product Bundle Identifer" in XCode for different Configurations. I have created an "Enterprise_Distribution" configuration for my app and over-riden the bundle ID for it.

[image]

More details [here](http://nilsou.com/blog/2013/07/29/how-to-have-two-versions-of-the-same-app-on-your-device/).

Comment: I know. I am using this way. Let me ask you one question. When you want to update project ? Which way do you follow ? You update your project seperately ?

Comment: Salih does that answer your question about updating?

Comment: about every step of developing app. My question is about your bundle ids when you using both com.organization.helloworld and com.organization.helloworld.beta, you use different projects for different bundle id's ?

Comment: I use the same xcode project & workspace for both apps. See screenshot above to see how I've configured a different bundle ID for different configurations.

Comment: I think you used multiple targets for different bundle id's ? Am I Right ? Because my projects not showing enterprise_Distirbution section.

Comment: This worked for us very well until Xcode 8. In Xcode 8 it complains about the app group not being handled by the enterprise provisioning profile. See my issue here (still not answered)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39578705/xcode-8-multiple-accounts-1-for-enterprise-1-for-app-store-and-signing-issue